# Base64 Encode email address in url parameter within a link in the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, parameters, base64

I am trying to base64 encode a subscriber's email address within a link in an email.

I am using Exact Target and trying to encode the personalization string %%emailaddr%%.

this is what I have so far:

```
%%[
VAR @email

SET @email = Base64Encode(RequestParameter(emailaddr))
]%%
```

The link:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page.aspx?&param1=",@email">
```

I have done and seen reference to doing this within microsites or landing pages but nothing email specific.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
%%[

VAR @email

/* emailaddr is a personalization string, so no need to request it */
SET @email = Base64Encode(emailaddr)

]%%

<!-- need to refrence @email as an AMPScript variable --> 
<a href="http://example.com/page.aspx?&param1=%%=v(@email)=%%">
```